# WordPress wp_posts table is huge - how can I reduce it?

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

I have a site with a massive database (1Gb) that I'm struggling to reduce in size. It seems that the wp_options table had something like 350,000 rows; most of which were transients. I installed WP Optimize and cleared them but it only cleared about 50Mb from the size of the database.

In phpMyAdmin I can see that the wp_options table now has 23,966 rows but the data size is 947Mb. The index size is just 4.9Mb. I've tried optimizing the table but this doesn't do anything to reduce the overall size of the database.

Any suggestions on what I should do now?

Thanks in advance for all help and suggestions!

Comment: 1Gb is not a "massive" database... 50Gb becomes a "large" database. "massive" would be something like 1Tb... Why do you want to reduce it... ?

Comment: Ok, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: 1Gb for a WordPress website is rather large comparatively speaking. We're talking about an e-commerce site with a couple of hundred products and a modest volume of sales. Other sites that I have managed of a similar nature have significantly smaller databases. The size of the database is very much out of proportion to what the site is so something isn't right. I have, however, now discovered that a single plugin is responsible for the vast majority of the data. The plugin connects the site to an ERP system (Specter).

Comment: It may also depend on how you check for database size. In MySQL, a database file NEVER reduce in size. So if you delete data, you'll not get more free space. You have to export your database, delete it, and remake it.